# Right way to add table column in laravel 4

Tags: database, laravel, migration

I created a migration table (say posts) with various table entries like user, post_id, content etc. I seeded the table and moreover the database is now populated with a lot of posts.

But I forgot to add an entry 'slug' to it. So now I want to add this entry to the table. What is the best way to do this without messing up with existing data?

Shall I edit migration file and migrate:refresh ? or just add an entry in the database (using phpmyadmin or anything else).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122666/laravel-migration-add-field-after-data-is-in-table) answer says new migration should be created but it hasn't made clear after creating new migration (or updating the existing one), one should migrate:refresh or not. am I missing something?

Comment: Create new migration and use `Schema::table` instead of `Schema::create`, that's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory you should create new migration with:

```
Schema::table('posts', function($table)
{
    $table->string('slug');
});
```

[Reference](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/schema#adding-columns)

and migrate, it will add this column to your database.

Of course when developing your application alone you can also alter existing migration, remove database content and migrate again and assuming you have all data in your seeds you can repopulate data again but probably it will be considered by many as bad practice.